# What is the co-kernel of the morphism of vector bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a surface, and $i:C\subset X$ be a smooth curve. Let $A$ be a line bundle on $C$, and $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$ on $X$.

Suppose there is a surjection: $E\longrightarrow i_*A\longrightarrow 0\\$,
then we get an exact sequence $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad0\longrightarrow F\longrightarrow E\longrightarrow i_*A\longrightarrow 0$.

Now $i_*A$ is torsion, we have $(i_*A)^*=0$. Therefore taking the dual sequence, we get

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 0\longrightarrow E^*\longrightarrow F^*\longrightarrow Q\longrightarrow 0$.

What is the co-kernel $Q$? How do we get it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $Q= \mathcal{Ext}^1(i_* A, \mathcal{O}_X) = \mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_C, \mathcal{O}_X)\otimes i_* A $ ?

Comment: @Mostafa, by $\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_C,\mathcal{O}_X)$ do you mean $\mathcal{Ext}^1(i_*\mathcal{O}_C,\mathcal{O}_X)$?

Comment: Yes,  I'm not confident on the second equality,  but it seems to be true for line bundles A.